# Why my play console personal account need verifcation with originaztion information

Tags: android, google-play-console

I bought the play console account with personal. But when I login to play console , I need to verify my account with Organization. How can I do that?I share my screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi did you ever figure this issue out?

Comment: @AdrianCarolli. No, you face the same issue?

Comment: Yup I do... I contacted Google but no response yet. I will let you know if I hear anything.

Comment: @AdrianCarolli.Sure. I will